# Angular 4 communication between services

Tags: angular

I have two services: SharedDataService (SDS) and FilterService (FS). SDS handles my API stuff. It goes shopping for my user, employees, observations. It also handles sending stuff to the back end. FS handles a lot, but not all of the stuff that happens on screen. With my interaction service I should (if I can get the damn thing working) be able to filter my list of stuff by the date it was entered, by employee, by some categories, or by all or some of those joined together.

Now, here's my problem. How do you get two services to talk to each other? I need some information in the FS that comes from the SDS (user and observations). How do I get them to talk?

I've tried:

```
    //SharedDataService.ts
    public observations: Observation[] = [];
    private observationsSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.observations);
    observations$ = this.observationsSource.asObservable();

    public getObservations(jobcode: string, loc_name: string): 
    Observable<Observation[]> {
       return this.http
         .get(API_URL + '/quick-interactions/get-observations/' + jobcode + '/' + loc_name)
         .map(response => {
         this.observations = response.json();
         this.observations.map((observation) => new Observation(observation));
         return this.observationsSource.next(this.observations);
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    //FilterService
    constructor(
      private sharedDataService: SharedDataServiceService
    ) {
        sharedDataService.employee$.subscribe(employee => {
          this.employee = employee;
        });

        sharedDataService.observations$.subscribe(observations => {
          this.observations = observations;
        });
     }
```

but that doesn't get me what I need. I tried it as just an Observable instead of a BehaviorSubject. I even tried it as just a straight call to a shareObservations method that returns this.observations. None of them have worked.

Anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: You are right that you should not need the behavior subject. A service should be able to access another service using dependency injection as you have it in your code above. Could you elaborate on how it is not working?

Comment: I've got a ton of console.logs that I removed for the question. When the app loads, I can see in one of them that the SDS has retrieved 292 observations, but in the FS the console.logs say "null". So even though SDS is getting the observations, they're not being shared with FS. I suspect that FS is running before SDS finishes it's shopping, but even with them as observables the data never gets to FS.

Comment: Give us more of your services code snippet. BTW, have you placed `@Injectable()` right before your services class?

Comment: @Injectable() is there in both services. I'm honestly not sure that more code snippet would be useful since the none of the other code in either relate to sending this particular bit of data from one to the other. Employee and Observations are the only pieces that need to get sent to FS. Is there something else in particular you'd like to see? My imports? The code in my ultimate parent component where getObservations are called? They both work. It's just this bit of getting observations from SDS to FS that isn't playing nicely.

Comment: How does your component code look like, which handles this?

Answer (score 1):

I would skip the `BehaviorSubject` altogether and instead from component call a method in `FilterService`, which calls method in `SharedDataService`, so something like this:

**Component:**

```ts
constructor(private filterService: FilterService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.filterService.getMyData(jobcode: string, loc_name: string)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
}
```

**FilterService:**

```ts
constructor(private sharedDataService: SharedDataService) { }

getMyData(jobcode: string, loc_name: string) {
  this.sharedDataService.getObservations(jobcode: string, loc_name: string)
    .map(data => { 
       // do whatever you need to do with your data here, then return
       return data;
    })
}
```

and then finally the **SharedDataService** which gets your data from API:

```ts
constructor(private http: Http) { }

getObservations(jobcode: string, loc_name: string) {
  return this.http.get('url here')
    .map(response => response.json().map(res => new Observation(res))))
}
```

Here's a **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnhaxu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)** with some different variable names etc, but does the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to look like this (now without the BehaviorSubject):

```
    this.sharedDataService.getObservations.subscribe(observations => {
      this.observations = observations;
      console.log(this.observations);
    });
```

with the console.log *within* the subscribe, it outputs undefined?

Here is the SDS in a simplified version:

```
public getObservations(jobcode: string, loc_name: string): 
Observable<Observation[]> {
   return this.http
     .get(API_URL + '/quick-interactions/get-observations/' + jobcode + '/' + loc_name)
     .map(response => <Observation[]>response.json())
     .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: It outputs an empty array.

Comment: What if you take off all of the extra behaviorSubject stuff as shown in my answer above. Does that change the display?

Comment: still gives me an empty array in FS, but now my console looks hell with all the stringified observations.

Comment: Wait ... the subscribe code needs to change now that we took out the behaviorSubject. I'll update the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the implementation of two services **Waiter and Customer** . When Customer is hungry then the waiter is called using waiter service.

```
@Injectable()
export class Waiter{

  dish:string = 'Pizza';

  constructor(){}

  getSomething(){
    return this.dish
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Customer{

  constructor(private waiter:Waiter){}

  whenHungry(){
    return this.waiter.getSomething()
  }
}
```